# Is there a function that return the arguments (and their descriptions) of a function?

Tags: r

I have not found what I was looking for on Google and Stack. I also looked at `?help` function documentation but got no real answer so I will ask my question here : **Is there a function that return the arguments (and their descriptions) of a function?**

I think an example is the best way to add some clarity to my question.
I would like to know if I can do something along the line of :

`some_function(fct = print(), arg_number = 1)`

Where the output would be the first argument of the `print()` function :

```
"x  an object used to select a method."
```

Even a function returning a list of all the arguments could probably do the job.

Thank  you

Comment: Have you checked `match.call` or `match.fun`. Not clear. about the expected output

Comment: Thank you Akrun, I'm gonna take a look at ``match.call``. I don't know how I can make the expected output more clear tho. I simply want to return the arguments from a function as character strings or even a list of character strings (if the function is to return all the arguments at once).

Comment: Something like `f1 <- function(a, b) {
      as.list(match.call())

};

f1(3, 4)`

Comment: @akrun I think you might be on something, thank you, I'm doing some test with your code.

Comment: It will returns the names and the values as a `key/value` pair list

Comment: Thanks Akrun, I got something close to what I was looking for!

Comment: formalArgs(dplyr::mutate) ?! @Gainz

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Yes it's a really good option too, thanks. It's still only the arguments names tho, seems like the definition can't be obtain this way.

Comment: @Gainz and what is that

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that returns arguments of a function (and their default values). It's called `formals`. From its help page:

> **Description**. Get or set the formal arguments of a function

It is also convenient to use `View` to inspect function definitions:

```
View(function_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look at ``formals()``. I know about the ``View()`` function but that's not what I need. I don't need to simply look at them but to get the arguments as character strings.

Comment: @Gainz The return value of `formals` are symbols, to have character values, try `names(formals(your_function))`. Compare this with `str(formals(your_function))`

Comment: @RuiBarradas That's what I figured, thank you! Do you think it is possible to also get the definition of the argument? IE: if using ``print()`` then ``formals()`` will return as first argument ``"x"``. Is it possible to get ``"x an object used to select a method."`` instead?

Comment: @Gainz Maybe you are looking for `args`? The return value of this will probably have to be parsed, though.

Comment: @Gainz I doubt this is possible. In order to do that, you need to parse an Rd file for the function.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yeah I think I'll have no choice to parse those values. Thank you.

Comment: @slava-kohut That's what I think too, thanks for the information and your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To get the help descriptions of each argument, you need to look at the help pages.  This is complicated, but RStudio does it.  You could look through their source on https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio, or look at the R sources to see how the check code does things.  The function to look at in R is `tools::checkDocFiles`.